# Error en sitio wordpress por SSL vencido

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Tengo un sitio cuyo SSL venció y tanto en la página como en el admin no me deja ver el contenido.

> La conexión no es privada
>       Es posible que los atacantes estén intentando robar tu información de globalwmexico.com (por ejemplo, contraseñas, mensajes o tarjetas de
>   crédito). Más información
>       NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Cuando configuré el sitio para soportar SSL recuerdo haberlo hecho en las opciones de WP-ADMIN, sin embargo, por el motivo descrito arriba no tengo modo de acceder para pasarlo temporalmente a HTTP en lo que se resuelve la vigencia del certificado.

Traté de modificar el configuration.php para cambiar la url a http:

```
var $live_site = 'http://globalwmexico.com/globalwmexico';
```

Y en la base de datos busqué sin éxito en la tabla wp_options algo que pudiera ayudar a cambiarlo. También veo que no se generó el .htaccess porque en su momento no utilicé Permalinks.

¿Alguna otra forma en la que pueda cambiarlo a HTTP o deshabilitar desde base de datos o archivos de configuración?

Comment: ¿El navegador no te da ninguna opción de aceptar la excepción? Normalmente lanza este tipo de avisos para alertar al usuario, pero no debería bloquear el acceso al contenido

Comment: Si tu preoblema es que no puedes acceder a wp-admin por tener el certificado caducado, como comenta @OscarR, puedes añadir la excepción desde el navegador y así puedes reconfigurar tranquilamente.

Comment: No me permite acceder para nada, normalmente me topaba en otras ocasiones que permitía acceder mediante un link que decía "Avanzado" y Continuar al sitio, haciendo efectivamente una excepción.

Comment: Como sugerencia, prueba con otros navegadores, aceptar la excepción debería salir. Otro sugerencia es que verifiques que la fecha de tu dispositivo y la del servidor estén correctas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente resolví el problema abriendo mi sitio con Internet Explorer 11; a diferencia de otros navegadores éste sí permite ingresar al sitio pese a la advertencia de seguridad.

Una vez dentro modifiqué desde el administrador de WordPress lo que necesitaba.

Gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 3):

prueba poniendo esto en el wp-config.php para cambiar las url a http y deshabilitar el ssl

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );

define( 'force_SSL', false );
```

si usas un cdn como cloudflare talvez necesites entrar al panel y desactivar ahi tambien el ssl (o pedir un certificado a cf)

del lado del servidor
chequea que apache/nginx aceptan conexiones en el puerto 80 y no solo en el 443
y que no haya un rewrite rules en el .htaccess cambiando el protocolo